# Chown Not Permitted, Has full Sudo Access?

Tags: macos, ansible

I have an [Ansible role which I'm trying to migrate to macOS](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-go-dev/pull/20).

The following step fails:

```
- name: get go user details
  command: sh -c 'echo $HOME'
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ go_user }}"
  become_flags: -Hi
  changed_when: false
  register: go_user_check
```

The error emitted is:

```
TASK [default : get go user details] *******************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user (rc: 1, err: chown: /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1533765311.28-97292171123102/: Operation not permitted\nchown: /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1533765311.28-97292171123102/command.py: Operation not permitted\n}). For information on working around this, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user"}
```

This same step works just fine on all the Linux distributions 
I'm testing against. When I execute `sudo -Hiu username sh -c 'echo $HOME'`, I get what I would expect: `/Users/travis`.

When I execute the following:

```
ansible -i 127.0.0.1, -c local --become --become-user travis \
    -m command -a 'sh -c "echo $HOME"' all
```

I get exactly what I'd expect, `/Users/travis`.

I'm reading the [documentation linked to by Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user) but I'm not seeing a workaround.

Is there a different way I should be executing this on OSX?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to proceed with the following modification:

```
diff --git a/tasks/discover/go.yml b/tasks/discover/go.yml
index 090ce7d..f0c2b89 100644
--- a/tasks/discover/go.yml
+++ b/tasks/discover/go.yml
@@ -3,9 +3,10 @@
   command: sh -c 'echo $HOME'
   become: true
   become_user: "{{ go_user }}"
-  become_flags: -Hi
   changed_when: false
   register: go_user_check
+  vars:
+    ansible_ssh_pipelining: true

 - name: set go user home
   set_fact: go_user_home="{{ go_user_check.stdout_lines[0] }}"
```

Pipelining appears to dodge the file modification that is failing. Unfortunately, I don't have the answer as to *why* it's failing, so other answers are still welcome as I'd like to get to what is actually happening.

There appear to be a lot of caveats to using Ansible on macOS, so I will probably have to have my tasks diverge completely based on whether it's Linux or macOS.